# Obtaining input Data file within RScript from an external system

Tags: r

I have a Rscript which is called from external system.External system provides some input data which is processed by Rscript to generate some statistical inference.

But How does both environments(R and External System) talks among each other?
Can we pass whole data(Data size is hundreds of MB) in some R recognized format as "argument" while invoking the Rscript?

What are the other feasible solutions available in this context?Please suggest.

Comment: can you give us the code of your R script ? By external system, do you mean a batch file ?

Comment: @etienne :- It may be a batch file(we are searching all options). Data are generated by a BPM platform which should be passed to R script for further analysis and generate some statistical significance

Comment: What is the format of the data ? .csv, .txt ?

Comment: Data Can be of ".csv" / "txt"/located at DB which has no access to Rscript.Data must be passed to RScript.

Comment: Can you use a commad such as `read.csv` ?